# Why does vuetify progress bar not update its value, if we use value from object

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a list of progress bars

```
<div v-for="item in projects">
   <v-progress-linear  v-if="item.status === 'In_Progress'"
                       color="light-blue"
                       height="10"
                       :value="progress[item.name]"
                       striped />
</div>



data () {
        return {
            intervalId: null,
            progress: {},
            projects: [
                {
                    name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
                    trainingError: '??',
                    predictionError: '??',
                    inQueue: 1,
                    status: 'In_Queue',

                },
            ],
        }
    },
```

I receive projects from the server. If status of project is In_Progress, its progress is requested from the server. I simulate the server's response as follows:

```
changeStatus() {
            const projName = this.projects[0].name

            if(this.projects[0].status === 'In_Queue'){
                this.projects[0].status = 'In_Progress'
                this.progress[projName] = 0
                return;
            }


            if(this.projects[0].status === 'In_Progress' && this.progress[projName] < 100){
                this.progress[projName] += 25
                return;
            }

            if(this.projects[0].trainingError === '??') {
                this.projects[0].status = 'Done'
                this.projects[0].trainingError = Math.random()
                this.projects[0].predictionError = Math.random()
                delete this.progress[projName]
                return;
            }

            clearInterval(this.intervalId)
        },
click() {
        if(this.intervalId){
            clearInterval(this.intervalId)
            this.projects = [
                {
                    name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
                    trainingError: '??',
                    predictionError: '??',
                    inQueue: 1,
                    status: 'In_Queue',
                 },
             ]
         }

         this.intervalId = setInterval(this.changeStatus, 10000);
    }
```

Progress bar's line is changing, **BUT** it changes, if i maximize and minimize window.

***--- Trying to solve #1 ---***

I tried this topic: [Vuetify progress bar does not synchronize the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708334/vuetify-progress-bar-does-not-synchronize-the-value)

I have put inside the `<style>` suggested hack:

```
.v-progress-linear__bar, .v-progress-linear__bar__determinate {
  transition: none;
}
```

But this hack doesn't work.

So what am i doing wrong? Progress bar's line updates only if i update window.

Comment: you should always define a key for v-for elements (and not the index), especially when conditionally rendering items. if you don't, Vue may encounter problems tracking which of your items are changing.

Comment: @IgorMoraru this is a demo, i use progress bar inside the `data-table`. Undefined key - is not the problem